# How can I write this R expression in the pipe operator format?

Tags: r, pipe, programming-languages, data-science, magrittr

I am trying to rewrite this expression to magrittr’s pipe operator:

> print(mean(pull(df, height), na.rm=TRUE))

which returns 175.4 for my dataset.

I know that I have to start with the data frame and write it as >df%>% but I’m confused about how to write it inside out. For example, should the na.rm=TRUE go inside mean(), pull() or print()?

UPDATE: I actually figured it out by trial and error...

```
>df%>%
+pull(height)%>%
+mean(na.rm=TRUE)
+print()

returns 175.4
```

Comment: see `?mean`. `na.rm` is an argument to `mean`

Comment: have you experimented a little bit?  Also, tangentially: I'm always a little bit puzzled why people are trying to get such "pure tidy" expressions, except maybe for pedagogical purposes:  `print(mean(df$height), na.rm=TRUE)` (or `(mean(na.omit(df$height)))`) seems perfectly easy to understand ...

Comment: what have you tried so far?  please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good practice to make a reproducible example, with dummy data like this:

```
height <- seq(1:30)
weight <- seq(1:30)
df <- data.frame(height, weight)
```

These pipe operators work with the majority of the tidyverse (not just magrittr). What you are trying to do is actually coming out of dplyr. The na.rm=T is required for many summary variables like mean, sd, as well as certain functions used to gather specific data points like min, max, etc. These functions don't play well with NA values.

```
df %>% pull(height) %>% mean(na.rm=T) %>% print()
```

Unless your data is nested you may not even need to use pull

```
df %>% summarise(mean = mean(height,na.rm=T))
```

Also, using summarise you can pipe these into another dataframe rather than just printing, and call them out of the dataframe whenever you want.

```
df %>% summarise(meanHt = mean(height,na.rm=T), sdHt = sd(height,na.rm=T)) -> summary
summary[1]
summary[2]
```